# MYSQL Select One Row With Less

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I'm making a database for a unit and I need a query that selects the vet with less appointments assigned so I can assign the next appointment to him or her. I don't know how to start, but I'm pretty sure I'll have to use variables here. Those are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff (

    stafId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    stafAdd VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    stafConNum VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    stafEma VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    stafFirNam VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    stafLasNam VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    stafPos ENUM('nurse', 'vet') NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (stafId)

) engine = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vet (

    vetId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FOREIGN KEY (vetId) REFERENCES staff(stafId),

    PRIMARY KEY (vetId)

) engine = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS appointment (

    appoId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    appoDat DATETIME NOT NULL,
    appoPetId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED,
    FOREIGN KEY (appoPetId) REFERENCES pet(petId),
    appoVetId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED,
    FOREIGN KEY (appoVetId) REFERENCES vet(vetId),

    PRIMARY KEY (appoId)

) engine = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by looking up the mysql [MIN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) function. Follow that up with learning about [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)s and you'll be breezing through this.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the vet's with the number of appointment like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        vet.vetId,
        COUNT(*) AS nbrOfAppointment
    FROM
        vet
        JOIN appointment
            ON vet.vetId = appointment.appoVetId
) AS tbl
ORDER BY tbl.nbrOfAppointment ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

This Request gives you the number of appointement per vet ordered by number of appointement.

```
Select vet.id, count(*) as nb_appointement 
from vet
inner join appointement app on vet.vetId = app.appoVetId 
group by vet.id
order by nb_appointement asc
```